# Both commands 'pip uninstall sklearn scikit-learn' are stuck, how to delete it properly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__file__
'C:\\Users\\Kenzhegaliyev_EK\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\__init__.py'
```

the pkg name is sklearn. 
 I tried both

```
pip uninstall sklearn
pip uninstall scikit-learn
```

but either of the 2 is just stuck and completing.

How to delete and install `sklearn = 0.19.1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see you are running `pip` on Windows and I am assuming you are using `cygwin`. It might be the case that some of the messages are not visible. When `pip` hangs normally it would ask you *"Do you want to continue (y/n)"?*

Simply press `y` when the uninstalling process hangs and it should do the trick.

Alternatively, you can *force* it by running:

```
pip uninstall sklearn --yes
```

or

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn --yes
```

Finally, if you just need to upgrade `sklearn` to version `0.19.1`, you don't have to uninstall the older version; You just need to run the following:

```
pip install --upgrade sklearn==0.19.1
```

Comment: oh sweet, i forgot to say i run it in jupyter on windows - office pc and powershell is restricted, i can't use cmd line

Comment: damn i did run the first with --yes and it worked! INSTANTLY!

Comment: i waited for 1h yesterday  and it was waiting FOR ME lol  to 'press enter' and i could not see it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
pip install --upgrade sklearn==0.19.1.
```

To fully answer your question, I dont know why pip uninstall is not working for you. This can be an alternative though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Colab, use command like:

```
!pip install scikit-learn==1.1
```

This will automatically uninstall the current version `1.2`